# Listview not updating on propertychange

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

When i add/remove items from the list the listview is registered on, the item gets added/removed accordingly. But when i change a property of the list, resulting in a different ToString() value, the Listview doesn't update the change accordingly. If i reload the data after a restart of the app from a xml file, the ListView shows it's items accordingly. So i think i can exclude an issue with my ToString method. Or is it an issue that I'm using ToSTring() at all?

Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

**window.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWin"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="MainWindowViewModel"
    Title="Baronieverwaltung für DSA" Height="1000" Width="1500" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">
    <GroupBox  Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Header="Angestellte">
        <ListView Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding DieBaronie.Angestellte, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedAngestellterIndex}">
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{            
public Baronie DieBaronie { get; set; }

private void MethodThatChangesListViewItem()
{
        if (SelectedAngestellterIndex > -1)
        {
            DieBaronie.Angestellte[SelectedAngestellterIndex].FunktionWarenschau = true;
        }
        //I found some threads where the solution was some variation of 
        //those NotifyPropertyChanged... but none work :(
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DieBaronie.Angestellte"); 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DieBaronie");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("");
        NotifyPropertyChanged(null);

}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (null != handler)
    {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**DieBaronie.cs:**

```
public class Baronie
{
  public ObservableCollection<Angestellter> Angestellte { get; set; }
```

**Angestellter.cs:**

```
public class Angestellter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private Boolean _FunktionWarenschau { get; set; }
    public Boolean FunktionWarenschau
    {
        get
        {
            return _FunktionWarenschau;
        }
        set
        {
            //if i add a break point here, the debugger stops here as expected - with the correct value
            _FunktionWarenschau = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    //Method doesn't even get called after the change :(
    public override string ToString()
    {
        String val = Name + " ";
        if (_FunktionWarenschau)
        {
            val += "(Warenschau)";
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to know for sure, but yes...if you are relying on the implicit conversion of an object to a string via the `ToString()` method as a way of displaying your data, `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't going to do anything that would cause WPF to call `ToString()` again for your object. Usually the simplest implementation is to just have another property returning the value you want to display. Another option is to write an `IValueConverter` that would use the properties your `ToString()` method uses now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you suggested, the issue is with ToString() - this is not a property, so the WPF binding engine is not aware of any need to refresh the view.

In addition, with more complex MVVM scenarios, I believe it is convention to use Properties anyway, as you may build out your views to display more complex data (e.g. images) or customize the layout of your data further (e.g. panel of images + strings).

To solve your problem, I would recommend:

1. Create a property in your ViewModel to bind to. Here, you could simply bind to FunktionWarenschau and Name. Alternatively, you can create a new string property and have FunktionWarenschau either update your string property or simply call NotifyPropertyChanged with the new property name passed along.
2. Create a DataTemplate for your ListView (untested code to give you a flavor)

   ```
   <ListView Height="200"
             ItemsSource="{Binding DieBaronie.Angestellte, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedAngestellterIndex}">
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding FunktionWarenschau}"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
   ```